# TypeError: Text.isText is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs, react-slate

I'm following a **slate** tutorial on https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/04-applying-custom-formatting

There is a function call Text.isText(n), I keep getting Type:Error Text.isText is not a function

```
toggleBoldMark(editor) {
    const isActive = CustomEditor.isBoldMarkActive(editor)
    Transforms.setNodes(
      editor,
      { bold: isActive ? null : true },
      { match: n => Text.isText(n), split: true }
    )
  },
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try importing Text

`import { Text } from 'slate';`

Comment: Their docs are like swiss cheese